# Actions on Google not showing device registration option

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to use google assistant in a raspberry pi project. I have created my developer project. However, there is no option to register the device model as instructed in Google Assistant SDK for Devices ->

https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/register-device

As a result i am not able to execute the sample code.

Answer (score 7):

The link was also not there for me. I just started guessing at the URL until I found it:

`https://console.actions.google.com/u/0/project/{your-project-name}/deviceregistration/`

This allows you to follow the [instructions in their docs to register a device](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/register-device).

Answer (score 2):

Since i was not able to do it from the front end consol, I tried the "Alternative ways to register". I was able to register the device eventually by using the Registration Tool Commands mentioned at https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/device-registration/device-tool#register-device

I did it after downloading the credentials file and authenticating it. However, i believe even authentication can be done with these commands.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project, you'll see a bunch of cards like "Build an X action". Click "Skip" in the corner to create a blank project that will have the device registration tab available.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I tried it. However, in tab on the left under "Measure" -> "Advance Options" there is "Backend services" option. This is where , as per the documentation, "Device registration" should be.